# Perforce: Sync master data but directly download derived data as well

Tags: version-control, perforce

This must have been solved somewhere but I can't find a straightforward answer.

The Perforce depot has **code**, **master data**, and **derived data**. But only the code and master data need to be source-controlled. The derived data can be generated during nightly-build on the build machine.

Here is the problem: The users want to sync with the depot as usual and get **all three above**. So the derived data must be downloaded after user clicks "Get Latest Version" in P4V. They don't want to run extra scripts on their local machines either.

Is there anything I can do on the server side to make this happen?

**EDIT**

The reason why the derived data had better not be submitted:

The derived data are owned by a particular team as their products. These data are constantly edited by only that team on multiple machines and could have constant conflicts. So for their convenience, the data should not need to be checked out and checked in on every single edits because conflicts should be handled from the master-data end, so the derived data better be excluded from SCM.

The rest of the project teams simply consume these derived data in their work and require no change at all. They should only get one healthy batch of the derived data from the depot, say, once a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submit the derived data from the build machine each night after it's rebuilt.

Have the team that needs to rebuild it themselves exclude it from their client views.  This is easy to automate in various ways, e.g. via virtual streams or client spec triggers, but even if it's done "manually," it's only done once per workspace, so there's no maintenance cost.

For everyone else the derived data just syncs down normally, and you can use protections to make it read-only to everyone but the build machine if you want to make sure that nobody is checking it in when they shouldn't be.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify. Thanks for looking at it, and would you please advise again?

Comment: Updated answer.  Submitting the files and then fixing the problem of "I don't want this team to sync these files" is MUCH easier than "I want the server to trigger a specialized local tool automatically on everyone else's machine with no user intervention required".  :)

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!